# Google-Cloud-Speech API confidentiality

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I am using the google cloud speech api to convert voicemails from my clients in to text.  It is installed and working well.

My question is how secure is it?  Do google keep any of the data they collect?  Do google have a statement somewhere I can reference?  Am I breaking client confidentiality by passing the audio to google?

Any advice, or links would be appreciated.

Regards,

Tony

Comment: Google seems to have written up the story here ...

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/data-logging

The bottom line is that Google declares that (by default) they do not keep either the audio or transcription data.  However, there appears to be an opt-in story (NOT ON BY DEFAULT) where you can offer up your data for training purposes to Google to help Google train in return for pricing discount.